# Xpath for div based on span label

Tags: javascript, java, xpath

I need to figure out how to get the "Field value" from the below snippet based on the Field label.

```
   <div class = "class1">
       <span class= "class2">Field label</span>
    "Field value "
   </div>
```

I have tried

```
//span[normalize-space(text()) = 'Field label']/.."
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `following::` axis like this:

```
//span[normalize-space(text()) = 'Field label']/following::text()[1]
```

This returns the first `text()` node after the matched `<span>`. Use `normalize-space(...)` on the whole expression if you don't need the surrounding spaces.

Comment: This threw an error: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: The question is now closed, so you can also refer to the linked answer which states that you can only select element nodes by XPath (in Selenium, or, obviously, Java). So you could select the `<div>` with `//div[normalize-space(span) = 'Field label']` and iterate over the `text()` children. But this is not as precise as the above approach.